# Shared PKs and ObjectContext errors

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am using EF 4.3 in an ASP.NET WebForms application. I've started with model first approach with context object of type ObjectContext and POCO code generator (via T4).

At the beginning the Context was created at the beginning of every service method. While working on performance I decided to switch to context per web request. Unfortunately I have encountered an issue with Table-per-Type inheritance. I have two entities: Offer and OfferEdit. They are in a one to one relationship, and both share the same primary key. Basically an OfferEdit (OfferEdits table) is created once an Offer is being edited.

I query the context for a particular Offer entity more then once during web request. The error I get trying to execute:

```
var offer = Context.Offer.Where(o => o.Id == offerId).FirstOrDefault()
```

when this offer is already loaded to Context.Offer.EntitySet is

> All objects in the EntitySet 'RuchEntities.Offer' must have unique primary keys.
>   However, an instance of type 'Ruch.Data.Model.OfferEdit' and an instance of type'Ruch.Data.Model.Offer' both have the same primary key
>   value,'EntitySet=Offer;Id=4139'.

Will appreciate all advice.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are misusing TPT inheritance. To make it clear EF inheritance works exactly same way as in .NET - the entity can be either of type `Offer` or `OfferEdit`. You can convert `OfferEdit` to `Offer` but it is still `OfferEdit`. It can never be of both types which means you can never have `Offer` entity with `Id` same as `OfferEdit` entity because same key cannot be used by two entity instances. You also never can change instance of `Offer` to `OfferEdit` because .NET doesn't allow you changing type of existing instance.

Comment: My application has been working without any problems for a year. I've encountered problem after I switched to context per web request solution.